# CouchDB query to get the doc with MAX timestamp

Tags: mapreduce, max, couchdb, couchapp

My CouchDB document format as below and based on the price changes there can be multiple documents with same `product_id` & `store_id`

`{
  "_id": "6b645d3b173b4776db38eb9fe6014a4c",
  "_rev": "1-86a1d9f0af09beaa38b6fbc3095f06a8",
  "product_id": "6b645d3b173b4776db38eb9fe60148ab",
  "store_id": "0364e82c13b66325ee86f99f53049d39",
  "price": "12000",
  "currency": "AUD_$",
  "time": 1579000390326
}`

and I need to get the **latest** `document` (by `time` - the timestamp) for given `product_id` & `store_id`

For this, with my current solution I have to do two queries as below;

1. To get the latest timestamp. This returns the latest timestamp for given `product_id` & `store_id`

   `"max_time_by_product_store_id": {
     "reduce": "function(keys, values) {var ids = []
     values.forEach(function(time) { 
       if (!isNaN(time)){
         ids.push(time);
       }
     });
     return Math.max.apply(Math, ids)
   }",
   "map": "function (doc) {emit([doc.store_id, doc.product_id], doc.time);}"
   }`
2. Based on the latest `timestamp`, again I query to get the document with three parameters that are `store_id`, `product_id` & `time` as below,

   `"store_product_time": {
     "map": "function (doc) {
       emit([doc.store_id, doc.product_id, doc.time]);
     }"
   }`

This works perfectly for me but my problem is I need to do two DB queries to get the document and looking for a solution to fetch the document within one DB query.

In CouchDB selector also has no way to get the document by MAX value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CouchDB's [/db/_find](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html), you can descending `sort` the result and `limit` the result to one document as follows:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "_id": {
         "$gt": null
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "time": "desc"
      }
   ],
   "limit": 1
}
```

CURL

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/<db>/_find -d '{"selector":{"_id":{"$gt":null}},"sort":[{"time": "desc"}],"limit": 1}'
```

> Please note that an index must previously be created for the sort field `time` (see [/db/_index](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-index)).

Comment: One more thing is that need to create a INDEX for `time` as we sort by `time` key